# How to Convert Pandas Dataframe to Single List

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0    1       5       2
1    7       13
2    9       1
3            7
```

How do I convert to a single list such as:

```
[1, 7, 9, 5, 13, 1, 7]
```

I have tried:

```
df.values.tolist()
```

However this returns a list of lists rather than a single list:

```
[[1.0, 5.0, 2.0], [7.0, 13.0, nan], [9.0, 1.0, nan], [nan, 7.0, nan]]
```

Note the dataframe will contain an unknown number of columns. The order of the values is not important so long as the list contains all values in the dataframe.

I imagine I could write a function to unpack the values, however I'm wondering if there is a simple built-in way of converting a dataframe to a series/list?

Comment: The desired outcome list is missing **2** from `col3`.  Is that desired, or an oversight?

Comment: Sorry, yes that's a typo. Should be `[1, 7, 9, 5, 13, 1, 7, 2]` as you pointed out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following your current approach, you can flatten your array before converting it to a list. If you need to drop `nan` values, you can do that after flattening as well:

```
arr = df.to_numpy().flatten()
list(arr[~np.isnan(arr)])
```

Also, future versions of Pandas seem to prefer `to_numpy` over `values`

---

An alternate, perhaps cleaner, approach is to 'stack' your dataframe:

```
df.stack().tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use dataframe [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[np.nan,3,4,np.nan], "col2":['test',np.nan,45,3]})

In [13]: df.stack().tolist()
Out[13]: ['test', 3.0, 4.0, 45, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Ordered list (As per problem statement):**

Only if your data contains integer values:

Firstly get all items in data frame and then remove the `nan` from the list.

```
items = [item for sublist in [df[cols].tolist() for cols in df.columns] for item in sublist]
items = [int(x) for x in items if str(x) != 'nan']
```

**For Un-Ordered list:**

Only if your data contains integer values:

```
items = [int(x) for x in sum(df.values.tolist(),[]) if str(x) != 'nan']
```